# ¿Como cambiar formato de fecha en un datagridview en c# con postgres?

Tags: c#, sql, postgresql, datagrid, datagridview

Quiero modificar el formato de la fecha mostrada en mi datagridview: 
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

que la columna col_01 muestre el mismo formato de fecha que la columna col_02.

Mi consulta a la db postgres

```
NpgsqlConnection oConexion = new NpgsqlConnection("Username = postgres; Password = 123; Host= 192.168.0.1; Database= consulta");
        NpgsqlDataAdapter oda = new NpgsqlDataAdapter("select col_01, col_02, col_03, col_04, col_05, col_06, col_07, col_08, col_09, col_10, col_11, col_12, col_13, col_14, col_15, col_16, col_17, col_18, col_19, col_20, col_21, col_22, col_23, col_24, col_25  from rdi_" + cboboxmesatrabajar.SelectedValue + cboxanio.Text + "_e where col_01 = '" + cboxanio.Text + "-" + comboBoxmes.SelectedValue + "-" + cboboxdia.Text + "'", oConexion);
        DataSet ods = new DataSet();
        try
        {
            oConexion.Open();
            oda.Fill(ods);
            oConexion.Close();
            dgvdatos.DataSource = ods.Tables[0];

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
        MessageBox.Show("¡Consulta generada!");
```

la estructura de mi tabla en postgres

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

o habrá alguna otra manera de  autocompletar con datos de un textbox? sin afectar las demas columnas de la consulta db?

Answer (score 0):

Puede definir el formato en la propiedad de la columna

[Procedimiento para dar formato a datos en el control DataGridView de formularios Windows Forms](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/framework/winforms/controls/how-to-format-data-in-the-windows-forms-datagridview-control)

Entonces usarias

```
dataGridView1.Columns["col_01"].DefaultCellStyle.Format = "yyyy-MM-dd";
```

Lo que si recomendaria es que las columnas las definas en `tiempo de diseño` ya que si son dinamicas puede que no aplique una ver cargado el grid

Sino vas a tener que usar el evento `CellFormatting`

[Procedimiento para personalizar el formato de los datos en el control DataGridView de formularios Windows Forms](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/framework/winforms/controls/how-to-customize-data-formatting-in-the-windows-forms-datagridview-control)

en este evento se ejecuta por cada celda, detectas las celdas de esa columna y la aplicas formato dinamicamente mientras se crea cada valor, por eso decia que es mas facil si defines las columnas en diseño

```
private void dataGridView1_CellFormatting(object sender, DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e)
{

    if (dataGridView1.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].Name.Equals("col_01"))
    {
        DateTime dateValue;
        if (DateTime.TryParse((String)e.Value, out dateValue))
        {
            e.Value = dateValue.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Gracias, fue de mucha ayuda.